# SQL Server xml query can't return expected result

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have this xml data in my table as you can see :

```
<ArrayOfFlowDetailParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FlowDetailParameters>
    <DepartmentId>23</DepartmentId>
    <UserId xsi:nil="true" />
    <Username />
    <FullName />
    <ConfirmDateTime xsi:nil="true" />
    <Comment />
    <Status>Pending</Status>
    <AttachmentId />
  </FlowDetailParameters>
  <FlowDetailParameters>
    <DepartmentId>22</DepartmentId>
    <UserId xsi:nil="true" />
    <Username />
    <FullName />
    <ConfirmDateTime xsi:nil="true" />
    <Comment />
    <Status>Pending</Status>
    <AttachmentId />
  </FlowDetailParameters>
  <FlowDetailParameters>
    <DepartmentId>7</DepartmentId>
    <UserId xsi:nil="true" />
    <Username />
    <FullName />
    <ConfirmDateTime xsi:nil="true" />
    <Comment />
    <Status>Pending</Status>
    <AttachmentId />
  </FlowDetailParameters>
  <FlowDetailParameters>
    <DepartmentId>18</DepartmentId>
    <UserId xsi:nil="true" />
    <Username />
    <FullName />
    <ConfirmDateTime xsi:nil="true" />
    <Comment />
    <Status>Pending</Status>
    <AttachmentId />
  </FlowDetailParameters>
</ArrayOfFlowDetailParameters>
```

when i want to find the `departmentid` with `value=22` my query returns 0 result but when i search value=23 it returns 1 result i think it is because of [1].

```
 declare @departmentId nvarchar(max)
 set @departmentId=22
 select  Requests.*   from Requests
 where    
 and (FlowDetailParameter.value('(/ArrayOfFlowDetailParameters/FlowDetailParameters/DepartmentId/text())[1]','bigint') = @departmentId  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to query a list of requests where the FlowDetailParameter column's XML contains a record where the DepartmentId matches your @departmentId variable, right?

The [1] in your query specifies to only check the first occurrence of DepartmentId in each row's FlowDetailParameter XML. You won't get a match unless the *first* DepartmentId in the XML matches your parameter.

Instead, you can use the following query to find all requests that have a FlowDetailParameter matching the @departmentid variable using the [nodes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017) method.

```
SELECT r.*
FROM @Requests r
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
        FROM r.FlowDetailParameter.nodes('/ArrayOfFlowDetailParameters/FlowDetailParameters/DepartmentId') as Parms(DepartmentId)
        WHERE DepartmentId.value('.', 'bigint') = @departmentid)
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer, I am agree with @Max

Comment: Thank you max it works .could you please take look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52800805/xml-query-with-more-than-one-condition